# Is K6 a planar graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

Using the condition $m\leq3n-6$, where $m$ equals the number of edges in the graph and $n$ is the number of vertices, I reasoned that for $K6$, the number of edges is $2\times 6 = 12$. With the vertices being equal to 6, $3n-6 = 12$. So $12\leq 12$, and the inequality condition is satisfied. So, is this reasoning correct to show that $K6$ is a planar graph?

Comment: $K_5$ isn't even planar, let alone $K_6$. The complete graph $K_n$ has $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, because there are $(n$ choose $2)$ ways of choosing two vertices to connected by an edge.

Comment: @runway44 But the inequality holds for k6 and k5, why aren't they planar?

Comment: This condition is only necessary, not sufficient.

Comment: The inequality is *necessary*, but it is not sufficient. Any simple connected planar graph satisfies it, but satisfying the inequality does not guarantee planarity.

Comment: @runway44 I don't see either $K_6$ or "complete graph" in the question. Before rushing to answer, perhaps try to find out what the OP means by his weird notation $K6$. Apparently some graph with $6$ vertices and $12$ edges? Maybe its his personal notation for the octahedron graph, which of course is planar.

Comment: I do not think $K_6$ has $12$ edges. It has $(6\times5)/2$ edges, so $15.$

Comment: @user376343 Of course you're right, $K_6$ has $15$ edges. But the OP didn't mention $K_6$. The OP is talking about $K6$ and it's anybody's guess what he means by that, since he has not seen fit to clarify his question.

Answer (score 11):

Not even $K_5$ is planar, let alone $K_6$. There are two issues with your reasoning.

First, the complete graph $K_n$ has $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. There are $(n$ choose $2)$ ways of choosing $2$ vertices out of $n$ to connect by an edge. As a result, for $K_5$ the equation $E\le 3V-6$ becomes $10\le9$, which is false. This proves $K_5$ is not planar.

Second, even if $K_5$ did satisfy the inequality, that wouldn't be enough. Planar graphs satisfy the inequality, but not all graphs that satisfy the inequality are planar. A counterexample is the bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$. In general, the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ has $m+n$ vertices and $mn$ edges, so the equation $E\le 3V-6$ for $K_{3,3}$ becomes $9\le12$. Nonetheless, you can prove $K_{3,3}$ is nonplanar using Euler's formula $V-E+F=2$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136430/prove-that-k-3-3-is-not-planar).

[Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) says a graph is planar if and only if no subgraph is [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)) (i.e. topologically equivalent) to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, so these two "forbidden graphs" by themselves are the gatekeeper for all planar/nonplanar graphs.

Comment: (+1) perfect answer.